# Why can't I use cars in solo mode that I've unlocked in Career mode?

Tags: blur

I unlocked cars in Career mode in the game for PS3 Blur, but I do not find them. They are not available in the solo race.

Is it because they are a higher level? or is it simply that it might be usable in multiplayer and I do not see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing the career mode slightly, I found the cars I unlocked earlier. It functions by category. The cars I had won are Class C, and I was at the race level D. When unlocking, the category is indicated.